# Can the Observable call in Angular 4 be like jquery's sync ajax way?

Tags: javascript, ajax, angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I have some bussiness logic function to call , which has a logic that must use HttpGet , And I have to wait until it returns the result to contiune ,if i use jquery's ajax can simple do it all , do not know whether the Observable also has similar way?

---

I hope the resut is :

- John
- Andy

but now the result is only show **Andy**  :(

---

```js
function main(){  
/*
  I have more than 70 sharing rules to deal with different Logic
  (e.g. getAge , getSomthing...), in order to simplify the problem ,
  I only list two rules as a demonstration
*/
  methods = [
    getNameFromServer,
    getSomeOneName
  ];
  
  const result = [];  
  methods.forEach(method => {
    method(result);
  })
  
  console.log(result);
}

function getNameFromServer(result){
  Rx.Observable.of('John')
    .delay(1000)
    .subscribe(name => {   
      console.log('now async get name , but I need it will be sync')
      result.push(name)
    });
  
  // can I use sync Ajax like jquery's code?
  // $.ajax({ 
  //          ... ,
  //          async: false 
  //        })
  //  .done(response => result.push(response.xxx))
}

function getSomeOneName(result){
  result.push('Andy');
}


// execute
main();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.0.1/Rx.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Instead of `async: false` -> [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: your console.log(result); is running before the observable adds John to the result array. console.log(result) after result.push(name) within your observable

Comment: Because the observable finished after console.log(result);

Comment: thanks , I know Observable will end after console.log , but if I use jquery ajax and set async to false , it will execute before console.log and I get result I want : [ John  , Andy ]

Comment: I would recommend against synchronous http requests, as this blocks all of your js from executing while it waits for the http request to finish. I would leave the observable as asynchronous and move your result.push('Andy') after your result.push(name) in your observable success callback. This would give you your desired ['John', 'Andy']

Comment: @LLai I agree with your idea , because I think so , but the reason Why I would do that in reailty , the whole site I have more than 70 sharing rules to deal with different logic( e.g. getAge, getSomething... ) ,so I think to rewrite every rule as a Observable , the risk is bit big , I would prefer to be the smallest changes to comlete this matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any modern browser you can use `async`/`await` to get a synchronous behavior. You must:

- Declare your `main` as `async`
- Replace the `forEach` with `for`..`of` (callbacks don't work well with `await`)
- Convert your `Observable` to `Promise` to make it awaitable, then return it
- Replace `subscribe` with `do`. You still get the side effects but `do` returns the observable so you can immediately chain `toPromise`. The observer is automatically subscribed by `toPromise`

Code would be:

```js
async function main(){  

      methods = [
        getNameFromServer,
        getSomeOneName
      ];
      
      const result = [];
      for (let method of methods) {
        await method(result);
      }
      console.log(result);
    }
    
    function getNameFromServer(result){
      return Rx.Observable.of('John')
        .delay(1000)
        .do(name => {   
          console.log('now async get name , but I need it will be sync')
          result.push(name)
        })
        .toPromise();
      
      // can I use sync Ajax like jquery's code?
      // $.ajax({ 
      //          ... ,
      //          async: false 
      //        })
      //  .done(response => result.push(response.xxx))
    }
    
    function getSomeOneName(result){
      result.push('Andy');
    }
    
    
    // execute
    main();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.0.1/Rx.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, this is what I want ,and if I need to support IE 9 ,do not know you have any ideas?

Comment: No, it's not possible in IE, not even 10. Only from Edge on.